# Regex to remove newline character from string

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with python and I need a fast way to remove all instances of \n in a string.  Just to be clear, here is an example of what I want.

```
"I went \n to the store\n"
```

becomes

```
"I went to the store"
```

I'm thinking perhaps regex would be the best way.

Comment: I think regex is probably overkill here.

Comment: I actually want to do this over about 6 million strings (I probably should have mentioned that) that are much longer than the example string.  So I suggested regex for speed, but it still may be overkill

Comment: How long are the strings? Because while I doubt regex will be faster, but if the strings are long you might need to use a faster language, or a fast implementation of Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `str.replace`:

```
>>> "I went \n to the store\n".replace('\n', '')
'I went  to the store'
```

For equal spacing you can first split the string using `str.split` and then join it back  using `str.join`:

```
>>> ' '.join("I went \n to the store\n".split())
'I went to the store'
```

Comment: So .split() removes the \n's?

Comment: @user1893354 yes, it removes all types of whitespaces