# Removing Question marks from string

Tags: python, text-parsing

i'm trying to remove question marks from a string in python and I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do it is.  I assume searching each word for a ? is not the best way.  Just to clarify, I am looking to change this

```
"What is your name?"
```

to this

```
"what is your name"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to remove newline character from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935859/regex-to-remove-newline-character-from-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"What is your name?".replace("?","") #this is the most clear
#or
filter(lambda x:x!= "?","What is your name?")
#or
"".join(x for x in "What is your name?" if x != "?")
#or
"What is your name?".translate(None,"?") #this is my favorite
```

and many more

Answer (score 3):

`replace()` is simple and efficient:

```
>>> "What is your name?".replace("?", "")
'What is your name'
```

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion you should look at built-in string.replace() method.

```
result = "What is your name?".replace('?', '')
```